# Exclude Columns items but cant change main select

Tags: php, json

I am using the following code to generate json but I need to be able to only select certain columns to the output i thought this would work but its still outputting all column. I cant change the main function that thats why i thought and if statment would just worked here?

```
public function generate_json($table_data) {
    $results = array();
    $results = $table_data;
    if ($table_data)
    {
        foreach($table_data as $key => $row)
        {
            if( $results[$key]['images']='url')
                $results[$key]['images'] = $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']);

        }
     }

     return json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Can you please explian this  if( $results[$key]['images']=='url') . what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please add a `print_r($table_data);` as the first line of this function and then edit your question with the result of that array dump.

Comment: Plus, the first line of the function initializes `$results` to an empty array. Then the second line loads `$results` with the content of `$table_data` WHY?

Comment: @VikasUmrao thanks someone who dont critizie wants to help this function $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']); returns an array of data of columns that im not allowed to change so i am just wanting to allow certin columns printed out to the json i though that if would allow it i need url description and title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I am sure it will work or not

```
public function generate_json($table_data) {
    $results = array();

    if ($table_data)
    {
        foreach($table_data as $key => $row)
        {
            foreach($row as $key1=>$val1){
            if($key1=="url"){
            $results[$key]['images'] = $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']);
            }

        }
     }

     return json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Vikas it did not work i enclose an example of my json to see if you can finger out why ?

http://pastebin.com/C5cggzTx

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it a bit neater myself using the following

```
public function generate_json($table_data) {
    $results = array();
      $results = $table_data;

        if ($table_data)
          {
             foreach($table_data as $key => $row)
             {

            $images = $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']);

            foreach($images as $imgkey => $val)
            {
              $results[$key]['images'][$imgkey] = array('id' => $val['item_id'],'url' => $val['url'], 'description' => $val['description'], 'title' => $val['title']);
            }


            //  $results[$key]['images'] = $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']);


             }
          }


  return json_encode($results);

   }
```